# SAS to predictive model markup language

Tags: sas, pmml

I am currently working  on implementing a model developed in SAS. Is there a way to directly convert SAS code to PMML ?

Answer (score 1):

SAS EM offers great support for PMML. See: 
http://www.dmg.org/products.html

For Base SAS, I suggest you contact Zementis:
http://zementis.com/by-platform/

Answer (score 0):

PMML is just xml.  If you had some sample PMML you could take the model output data set from the model estimating proc such as proc logistic, and restructure it as the appropriate input to a datastep using an xml map to write the pmml that matched the layout of your sample.
Or you could write data step code to achieve the same result.